# Get textbox value in mouse paste event

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I would like to get the value from textbox when I click **right-click > paste**.

```
$('#searchbox').bind('paste', function (e) {
    alert($('#searchbox').val());
});
```

that's code doesn't complete my solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
$('#searchbox').bind('paste', function (e) {
    setTimeout(getTextValue, 10);
});

function getTextValue() {
    alert($('#searchbox').val());
}
```